# How to run UI Tests with modules and dynamic feature

Tags: android, testing, gradle, dynamic-feature-module

I'm currently playing around with the dynamic features. I'm not able to run any UI tests.

My app has three modules as shown on the diagram:

[image]

- **app** - the usual module
- **dynamicFeatureA** - the dynamic feature module. It must depend on **app**. That's a requirement when implementing dynamic features
- **shared** - a module containing some shared logic and 3rd party libraries. All my testing / mocking libraries are here as well

Down below you will find the **build.gradle** files for each of the modules.

### app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable = false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicFeatureA']
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'

    api 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0'
}
```

### shared

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Retrofit + OkHttp
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.1'

    // Tests
    api("junit:junit:4.13.1")
    api 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    api 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    api "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    api "io.mockk:mockk:1.10.4"
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    api "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.10.4"
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.2.2'
    api 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    api 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    api 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    api 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
    api 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'
    api 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.3.0'

    // Kotlin
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10"
    api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.4'

    api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    api "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
}
```

### dynamicFeatureA

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":app")
    implementation project(":shared")
}
```

When trying to run my UI tests I get the following errors

```
Android resource linking failed
/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d3cf80163c3f5e54a1f3dc792b3bfaac/jetified-core-1.9.0/AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-226: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.PlayCore.Transparent (aka com.test.test.dev.test:style/Theme.PlayCore.Transparent) not found.
    
/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2bbe030940076efec6cce94c1a3439fe/jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:69: AAPT: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka com.test.test.dev.test:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem ? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @silaros88 no, still nothing

Comment: What is your test class? Are you launching an activity from dynamic feature module?